# Predict using a saved regression model

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I have trained an ANN model for a regression problem which takes 10 parameters as input and gives 1 output. After training, I saved the model as json and weights as a .h5 file using keras. Now I want to make predictions on the new data. I have loaded the model and my question here is how do I scale this single row of input values, before feeding it to the model? Some of the machine learning algorithms did not require scaling(Standardization/Normalization) So I could load those models and used for making predictions. How do I do in an ANN model, since we scale the data for training?

Comment: What did you use for scaling? If you used sklearn's library, you could simply save the scaler object as a pickle object and further use it while testing.

Comment: yes, I have used sklearn library. So along with model and weights, scaler should also be saved. Is my understanding correct? Is this how I should do when I deploy my model also.

Comment: Yes, you are right. At the time of deployment also that scaler should be used as it is trained on the training data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` for example and transfer the one-hot encoding to your web-service ( i'm guessing that's how you're using the model for inference ) via `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`. The pipeline will save the state of your fit on your training data and apply the same function on your production data.

Example :

```
pipeline1 = Pipeline([
                ('OneHotEncoder', OneHotEncoder())
            ])
pipeline1.fit(trainingdata.column1.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

This is how you create a pipeline containing the onehotencoder , fit your data on the pipeline. All is left is dumping your pipeline in a file, loading it later in your production environment, and call the transform method on your loaded pipeline :

```
joblib.dump(pipeline1,"pipeline1.joblib")
# Production environment
pipeline1 = joblib.load('pipeline1.joblib')
momo = pipeline1.transform(productiondata.column1.values.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
```

And here , the variable momo contains your production data with the pipeline ( containing the one-hot encoding operation ) applied to it.